# Tiempo de ejecucion en C

Tags: c

Estoy compilando un programa escrito en C. Quiero hacerle unos cambios y comprobar cuanto tiempo tarda tras compilar una porcion del código, he visto algunas opciones como  la biblioteca `time.h`, el problema es que el tiempo que tarda en realizar la porción de código que quiero medir es menor a 1 segundo, así que no puedo hacerlo con esa biblioteca. ¿Conocen alguna otra forma de medir tiempos de ejecución menores a 1 segundo?

Comment: y cual seria la duda? no queda claro que problema tenes en la pregunta. por favor, usa el boton [edit] y arregla la pregunta

Comment: @gbianchi pues la pregunta es clara no?, lo quiero hacer es medir el tiempo que tada el programa en darme las respuestas una vez le doy las entradas, es un programa que ordena palabras como un diccionario, le doy unas palabras y el las ordena, quiero saber cuanto tiempo tarda en darmelas ordenadas una vez se las doy

Comment: Tu comentario es mas claro que la pregunta. y para resumir, queres contar el tiempo de ejecucion de algo...

Comment: @gbianchi si, exacto eso es lo que quiero hacer, usando objectdocks

Comment: @edwinvargas la única manera que conozco de hacerlo en es con `<time.h>` y `clock()`. Si estás en un SO tipo Unix puedes usar `time 'archivoejecutable'`

Comment: @gabrielcoronel entiendo, pero es posible medir tiempo menores a 1seg utilizando <time.h>?, los ejemplos que he visto solo miden por segundos, y lo que quiero medir es menor a un segundo, ya probe con time.h, pero la medicion me da 0.000 segundos